# Template Literals with a ForEach in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, template-literals

Is it possible to return a string value in `ForEach` in a Template literal so it will be added in that place? Because if I log it it returns `undefined`. Or is that like I typed not possible at all?

```
return `<div>
                <form id='changeExchangeForViewing'>
    <label for='choiceExchangeForLoading'>Change the exchange</label>
    <div class='form-inline'>
    <select id='choiceExchangeForLoading' name='choiceExchangeForLoading' class='form-control'>

    ${Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        return "<option value='" + key + "'>" + obj[key] + "</option>"           
    })}
    `;
```

Comment: Related to my comment below: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwt6aLyp/1/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

No, because `forEach` ignores the return value of its callback and never returns anything (thus, calling it results in `undefined`).

You're looking for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which does **exactly** what you want:

```js
return `<div>
    <form id='changeExchangeForViewing'>
        <label for='choiceExchangeForLoading'>Change the exchange</label>
        <div class='form-inline'>
            <select id='choiceExchangeForLoading' name='choiceExchangeForLoading' class='form-control'>
                ${Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
                    return "<option value='" + key + "'>" + obj[key] + "</option>"
                }).join("")}
`;
```

Note that after mapping, the code uses `.join("")` to get a single string from the array (without any delimiter). *(I forgot this initially — been doing too much React stuff — but [stephledev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3112209/stephledev) pointed it out in [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49691319/157247).)*

That said, it might be easier to read if you break it up, and you can use an arrow function rather than a traditional function, perhaps with another template literal:

```js
const options = Object.keys(obj).map((key) =>
    `<option value='${key}'>${obj[key]}</option>`
);
return `<div>
    <form id='changeExchangeForViewing'>
        <label for='choiceExchangeForLoading'>Change the exchange</label>
        <div class='form-inline'>
            <select id='choiceExchangeForLoading' name='choiceExchangeForLoading' class='form-control'>
                ${options.join("")}
`;
```

Finally, I'll mention `Object.entries`, which gives you an arrow of `[key, value]` arrays, which you *might* want to use in mapping the options (or not, `Object.keys` is fine too):

```js
const options = Object.entries(obj).map((key, value) =>
    `<option value='${key}'>${value}</option>`
);
return `<div>
    <form id='changeExchangeForViewing'>
        <label for='choiceExchangeForLoading'>Change the exchange</label>
        <div class='form-inline'>
            <select id='choiceExchangeForLoading' name='choiceExchangeForLoading' class='form-control'>
                ${options.join("")}
`;
```

---

Side note: That's not a "string literal," it's a [*template* literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: My apologizes I taught it was a String literal. Thansk for the help it worked like charm.

Comment: Why don't people accept the answer? If things worked like a charm!

Comment: I think there's like 15 minutes in which you cannot accept

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 I need to wait 9 min

Comment: I'd suggest that it would be better form to move the code out to a function for neatness and so that a separate template literal can be used inside the callback.

Comment: @rockstar: Yes, I'd agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: But I can't understand. Why we can't use forEach, but we can use map?

Comment: @GalibHasanov - Because the result of calling `forEach` is always `undefined`, but the result of calling `map` is an array with the mapped contents.

Answer (score 20):

Since `map()` returns an array, @T.J. Crowder's answer will produce invalid HTML as the `toString()` method of an array will be called inside the template literal, which uses commas to delimit the array. To fix this, just append `join('')` to explicitly use no delimiter:

```
${Object.keys(obj).map(key => (
    `<option value="${key}">${obj[key]}</option>`
)).join('')}
```

Also, you can use template literals inside the map itself.

Comment: It's more useful, when you see a minor omission like that, to comment and let the answerer know. (I've been doing too much React lately!) SO is meant to be collaborative.

Comment: FYI anyone reading these comments on stephledev's answer, the fix is integrated into the accepted answer so there is nothing to see here. ;)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for in literals.